# Get data from Firestore and load in spinner

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Can you guide me how I can obtain data from a document in Firestore and load it in a spinner, I have a user model that I want to update and I want it to load the value of its charge in the spinner :/

In the Values ​​package I have a roles resource

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array name="combo_roles">
        <item>Administrador</item>
        <item>Colaborador</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

In the DatosUsuarioFragment fragment I get and fill the spinner in the onCreateView method like this:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_datos_usuario, container, false);

        mFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        
        spinnerRoles = root.findViewById(R.id.spinnerRoles);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getContext(), R.array.combo_roles, androidx.appcompat.R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinnerRoles.setAdapter(adapter);

        btnGuardarUsuario = root.findViewById(R.id.btnGuardarUsuario);

        if (id_usuario == null || id_usuario==""){
            
                    String rol = spinnerRoles.getSelectedItem().toString();

                    if (spinnerRoles.getSelectedItem().toString().isEmpty()){
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Seleccionar rol del usuario", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
                    }else{
                        GuardarUsuario(nombreCompleto, email, contraseña, rol);
                    }
                }
            });
        }else{
            GetUsuario();
            btnGuardarUsuario.setText("Update user");
            btnGuardarUsuario.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    
                    String rol = spinnerRoles.getSelectedItem().toString();

                    if (spinnerRoles.getSelectedItem().toString().isEmpty()){
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Seleccionar rol del usuario", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }else{
                        EditarUsuario(nombreCompleto, email, contraseña, rol);
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        return root;
    }
```

the getUser() method gets the data from me and binds it to each textView, spinner, etc. element.

```
private void getUsuario(){
        mFirestore.collection("usuarios").document(id_usuario).get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
                String nombreCompleto = documentSnapshot.getString("nombreCompleto");
                String email = documentSnapshot.getString("email");
                String contraseña = documentSnapshot.getString("contraseña");
                String rol = documentSnapshot.getString("rol");

                etNombresApellidos.setText(nombreCompleto);
                etEmail.setText(email);
                etContraseña.setText(contraseña);
                etConfirmarContraseña.setText("");

                if (rol == "Administrador"){

                }else if (rol =="Colaborador")
                {

                }
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Error al obtener los datos", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
```

All the textviews load me normally, but the spinner, how do I make the condition that if it has a Collaborator role, for example, in the spinner, that value is selected?

I have tried with spinner.setSelection(int position) but it doesn't work

[image: Collection Usuarios Firestore]

[image: Auth Usuarios]

[image: roles]

Or the best would be to create a roles collection in Firestore?

Comment: Try looking at [How to set selected item of Spinner by value, not by position?](https://intellipaat.com/community/24431/how-to-set-selected-item-of-spinner-by-value-not-by-position)

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors? Please respond using @AlexMamo

Comment: In the get User() method, in the part of the condition, I would like my spinner to load by selecting the correct data from the String variable role.

When I update my user, the textView loads the data normally but my spinner always loads "Administrator" for more than String role = "Colaborador" @AlexMamo

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. What exactly from that document do you need to add to the spinner?

Comment: Hello! I want to recover the "role" field of a document and select it in the spinner, so I can edit my user.  What would be the best way to implement it? Is it okay to create a resource in android studio or can I store the roles in a collection in Firestore? @AlexMamo

Comment: If that data is static, and doesn't change you can store it in a resource file. Otherwise add it tot he database.

Comment: They are static data, so how do I match the role field of the document and select it in the spinner? I have tried with spinner.setSelection(int position) but it doesn't work
@AlexMamo

Comment: "doesn't work" doesn't provide enough information so we can help. What exactly doesn't work? Do you have any errors?

Comment: What the getUsuario() method does is obtain a document and display those fields in the EditText in order to update a user. All editTexts load normally but in the if() I would like the spinner to load the role field that the user has in order to change it.

What happens is that the spinner always loads Administrator, if my user has a role = "Collaborator" my spinner still loads Administrator... that's why I want to know how to get the role field and load it in the spinner, I can't even with setSelection (int pos) @AlexMamo

Comment: The `rol` field inside your document is a string and doesn't hold multiple values so you can display it in a spinner.